# How i can pass column names from variables in plsql update statement

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE

  v_name  A.TRANSACTION_TYPE%TYPE   :='SALARY';
  v_salary    A.SALARY%TYPE := 1000;

BEGIN

  update A set v_name= v_salary where EMPID = 517; 
-- PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "v_name": invalid identifier
--update A set SALARY = 1000 where EMPID = 517;

END;

/
```

My idea is to update table columns , but these column names are stored in variable. Is there any way to pass column names from variable ? Is there any options apart from Execute Immediate

Comment: Why not execute immediate?

Comment: What's the reason you can't use dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your situation, but I've [written solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630068/sqlplus-spooling-to-multiple-files-from-pl-sql-blocks) where I wrote a script in SQL*Plus and it "wrote" (using `dbms_output.put_line` or even just `prompt`) another script that did queries, and the columns/tables in those queries was determined by the logic in the SQL*Plus script. Then I would execute as a script the output from my first script, and it would execute dynamically generated queries without ever needing `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 0):

The following idea may work for multiple columns that are typed the same... As written, it will update all columns every time for a given record, but only the column specified by `v_name` will be changed to the value set in `v_value`; the other columns are simply updated to their existing value. The idea can be played with using `DECODE`, `NVL` or other similar conditional operators.

```
 declare

 v_name varchar2(20):= 'SAL';
 v_value emptest.sal%TYPE := 5000;

 begin

 update emptest
 set sal = ( select case when v_name = 'SAL' then v_value else sal end from dual),
 comm = ( select case when v_name = 'COMM' then v_value else comm end from dual)
 where empno = 7369;

 commit;

 end;
```